# why the parameter 'scale' of tf.layers.batch_normalization is disabled when next layer is relu?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, batch-normalization

In the tensorflow documentation of tf.layers.batch_normalization,it is said" **When the next layer is linear (also e.g. nn.relu), this(the parameter of 'scale' ) can be disabled since the scaling can be done by the next layer.**" ? It seems wrong because when the next layer is nn.relu, the linear coefficient is an invariant constant(1), and the value won't be sacled.

Answer (score 0):

This was asked in a different SE, check out the answer here:

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22073/why-is-scale-parameter-on-batch-normalization-not-needed-on-relu

The reason is that there is always a linear combination applied to the data before passing the ReLU, so the scaling can be done by this "linear layer" pre-ReLU.